# Loop through classname within string of HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a html string which is being pulled in via AJAX.

Let's say it's:

`var htmlString = '<div class="post"></div><div class="post"></div>';`

I'm looking for a way to loop through those posts.

Normally I would do something like:

```
$('.post').each(function(i, currentElement){
    var htmlOfSinglePost = $(this).html();
});
```

The thing is I'm not sure how I can specify that it should search the `htmlString`, not the current DOM.

Is there a solution for this?

I'm trying to get an array of the post elements so I can pass them into the `appended()` method on MasonryJS, which can be seen here - http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#appended

Comment: You can simply do `$(htmlString).find('.post').each(...);`.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this : Use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get elements from `htmlString`

```
$(htmlString).filter('.post').each(function(i, currentElement){
    var htmlOfSinglePost = $(this).html();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8V4Gp/7/)**